# Set char to EOF

Tags: java

I have a map (`Map<Character, Integer> map`) that is being passed as a parameter. I want to check if map is of size one and only contains character EOF.

For example..

```
char c = 'EOF'; 

if(map.containsKey(c))
```

will not work

Comment: try char c = -1; that should work on most OS.

Comment: what do you mean by "a map that is being passed" can you please post the method signature (or at least some of it)?

Comment: char c = -1; will not compile since -1 is a integer.

Comment: EOF is not a character. Please show your code.

Comment: The solution was to use BitOutputStream and char c = output.EOF;

Comment: There is no such thing as an EOF character. Not a real question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no EOF character in a String. You simply iterate over each character in the String:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    char c = s.charAt(i);        
    //Process char
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Printing EOT    
System.out.println((char) 4);
```

This is not the same as EOF like you can read here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323750/difference-between-eot-and-eof
But if you plan to use it as delimiter (e.g. in a Stream) this could be used as a synonym.
Output on my machine: EOT
[screenshot of IntelliJ console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nev7M.png)